# How to offset line-height base line?

Tags: css, font-face

It is very common issue with `font-face`, e.g.

```
font: 20px/20px 'ITC Avant Garde Gothic Std'; font-style: 'book'; letter-spacing: 1px; text-transform: uppercase;
```

[image]

The problem is that I'd expect text vertically centered. However, it is not. Is there a way to offset the line-height base line? Without actually changing the `line-height`.

Answer (score 6):

The phenomenon depends on the font. It is up to the font designer to decide how the font uses its height. For example in Arial, when set solid, uppercase basic Latin letters are vertically centered, whereas in Verdana, they appear a bit lower (i.e., a little more space above than below).

You can fine-tune this by using relative positioning, but you then need extra markup, e.g.

```
<div><span>text</span></div>
```

with CSS for the `span` setting, say,

```
position: relative;
top: 2px;
```

This may cause nasty effects if the font used in the user’s browser is different from your expectations.

I did not consider the possible effect of `font-style: 'book'`, as I have no idea of what it might mean. No CSS resource I know mentions anything like that (the `font-style` values are unquoted keywords and do not inlcude `book`).

Comment: Just for you to know, the `font-style: 'book'` references to a font family member with style `book`. Thanks for the tip about relative positioning. The problem is though, that for instance, on Opera, the font appears as expected, ie. vertically centered. Therefore, applying a fix like yours, would not make it cross-browser compatible. This also makes it look as though this isn't font issue?